# Postman form-data sending complex object with file

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, postman

How to send (or maybe it's not possible?) complex object with file in Postman

My object:

```
class Client {
    private String clientName;
    private Platform platform;
}

class Platform {
    private String android;
    private String ios;
}
```

My Controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/evaluate", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ServerResponse> sendEvaluateForm(Client client,
        @RequestParam(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile files)
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

That's how I am sending request in postman:
[image]

It work's when I pass "clientName" which is basic field in Client. 
But I have no idea, how to pass Platform object.
I tried to pass in key: platform
and in value: {"android" : "asd", "ios" : "xxx"}
But i only got BadRequest(400)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to send both a JSON payload AND form data at the same time. You could embed the JSON as part of the form, but I think you'll need to do the unmarshalling manually in that case. I'm not entirely sure though, so perhaps someone with a bit more Spring Web experience could correct me (I generally stick to JAX-RS)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think you may be right. I tried to do this in in few different ways, but none of this worked (my friend is sending me this form+file  in JS). I could get this form in 1 object only with basic values, but it's pretty big (about 100fields) that's why I wanted to have it in seperate objects. 
But if I don't find the way how to send JSON+file I guess I will have to stick with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try send your client data as a plain string and parse it on the controller side.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/evaluate", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendEvaluateForm(@RequestParam ("client") String client,
                                                               @RequestParam(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile files) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Client clientobject = mapper.readValue(client, Client.class);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

And the postman request:

[image]

And your POJO classes:

```
class Client {
    private String clientName;
    private Platform platform;

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public Platform getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(Platform platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }
}

class Platform {
    private String android;
    private String ios;

    public String getAndroid() {
        return android;
    }

    public void setAndroid(String android) {
        this.android = android;
    }

    public String getIos() {
        return ios;
    }

    public void setIos(String ios) {
        this.ios = ios;
    }
}
```

Comment: WoW, I didn't think about that idea. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 32):

With **Postman** you can build a request containing **Files** and **Object** at the same time.

**Result** expected as backend **req.body**:

`{ street: '69 Pinapple street', city: 'Apple', zip: 6969, country: 'Pen' }`

[image: Postman ScreenShoot]

Comment: What if there is another level nested in ?

Comment: Any leads on how I can parse this to address object in golang when address is within another object say user.?